# How to find interface/ftdi/esp32_devkitj_v1.cfg in procedure 'script'?

Tags: debugging, ftdi, esp32, openocd, jtag

I'm trying to debug esp32 with ft2232d debugger , however at the openocd running script i'm getting this below mentioned error.

./openocd -s share/openocd/scripts -f ../interface/ftdi/esp32_devkitj_v1.cfg -f board/esp-wroom-32.cfg
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.10.0+dev-00703-g21687eb (2019-03-04-16:30)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
embedded:startup.tcl:63: Error: Can't find ../interface/ftdi/esp32_devkitj_v1.cfg
in procedure 'script' 
at file "embedded:startup.tcl", line 63

Now, i understand that my interface directory is not finding the esp32 cfg file but i searched and there is no such file.

Also Building openocd from the scatch has let to no bin files present in the main directory but these files are found in src folder.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Eclipse, try wrapping the file path of your config in double quotes. I had a similar error, and changing the argument to `-f "interface/stm32f429.cfg"` seemed to fix that error for me.